# Correct procedure to send a message to a client through websockets in PHP?

Tags: php, ratchet

I am developing a Symfony 6 project, in one of the screens I want to start executing a .jar whenever a button is pressed. I have manage to execute it asynchronously, but I have not being capable of informing to the client that the process has finish, therefore I decided to make use of websockets. I started by making a small design to test them, for some reason the client only connects to the web server, but it does not to receive any message.

This is my javascript file

```
// WebSocket setup
const socket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080');

socket.addEventListener('open', event => {
    console.log('Connected');
});

socket.addEventListener('message', event => {
    const message = JSON.parse(event.data);
    if (message.type === 'progress') {
        console.log(message.text);
    }
});

socket.addEventListener('close', event => {
    console.log('Connection closed');
});

// Fetch request
document.getElementById('upload-button').addEventListener('click', () => {
    const fileInput = document.getElementById('zip-file');
    
    const formData = new FormData(); // Create a new FormData object
    formData.append('del-file', fileInput.files[0]); // Append the selected file to the FormData
  
    fetch('/start-process', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: formData, // Send the FormData as the request body
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => console.log(data))
    .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error));
});
```

This would be the function called when the button is pressed

```
/**
     * @Route("/start-process", name="start_process", methods={"POST"})
     */
    public function startProcess(Request $request, MessageBusInterface $messageBus, WebSocketServer $webSocketServer): JsonResponse
    {
        // Start the asynchronous background job
        $message = ['type' => 'progress', 'text' => 'Job started'];
        $webSocketServer->broadcast(json_encode($message));

        // Simulate background job
        sleep(2); // Simulate work
        $message = ['type' => 'progress', 'text' => 'Job in progress...'];
        $webSocketServer->broadcast(json_encode($message));
        sleep(2); // Simulate work
        // Simulate background job completion
        $message = ['type' => 'progress', 'text' => 'Job completed'];
        $webSocketServer->broadcast(json_encode($message));
        return $this->json(['message' => 'Process finished']);
    }
```

[This is the only output that I receive in the console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wwmno.png)

Comment: One flaw in your plan is that your request is not asynchronous.  Your `fetch` call is going to block while those sleeps are going on, and won't return until they are done.

Comment: I'm a little confused about the data path here.  Who is calling `startProcess`?  Are you sure it's getting all three of those parameters?

Comment: Is there a way to do a `fetch` asynchronously?
The `startProcess` is called by the `fetch` through the path \start-process

Comment: The fetch is async relative to the browser, but it's not relative to the background job. So if the job runs a long time, the fetch request might time out and halt the job. The background job ought to run as separate process, and then it could broadcast directly to the websocket server as it progresses. Then the only purpose of the fetch request is just to request that a job is executed. The background service would notice the request and execute it. (Notifying the background job could be done by writing to a database table, or using a queue, or even a websocket message...)

Comment: But if the async is relative to the browser, then I do not understand why I am not receiving any message from the `startProcess`. Could it be because it is blocked by the `fetch` or not coded correctly?

Comment: It could be because it never reaches the websocket broadcast() commans, or something fails within the socket server, perhaps. We can't really tell just from looking at the code alone. Have you attempted to debug the php code in detail?

Comment: The point I was trying to make is that a normal route call in a web framework will not pass a message bus or a web socket to the handler.  Exactly HOW did you register `startProcess`?

Comment: @ADyson I do not know how to debug on PHP, my methodology to debug is printing lines, but I don't know how to use the debug bar. Since I do not receive any errors, I don't know how to see where are my mistakes.

Comment: @TimRoberts I don't know how `startProcess` is registered, this is my first Symfony project and I am guiding myself by looking at examples and asking ChatGPT. According to Chat  `MessageBusInterface` is part of Symfony's Messenger component, and by type hinting `MessageBusInterface $messageBus`, I am indicating that I want an instance of a message bus to be injected into your controller action, which is resolved by the framework. The same thing happens to `WebSocketServer`, but with the difference that I created that one.

Comment: You could also debug by logging data to a file, or using xdebug

Comment: See also https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.atatus.com/blog/debugging-in-php/amp/

Comment: P.s. `I am guiding myself by looking at examples and asking ChatGPT`...have you also spent lots of time reading the documentation and done a couple of in-depth, reputable tutorials so that you understand the fundamental concepts behind the examples? Otherwise it's like trying to run before you can walk. Also, ChatGPT is just a conversation-generating engine, it doesn't know how to code. It is notorious for generating plausible-looking but entirely non-functional code (as well as invented information and incorrect assumptions, etc.)

Comment: I haven't found too much information about WebSockets in the documentation and I haven't done in-depth tutorials. I was trying to guide myself with examples since I don't have too much time to finish this and I thought it would be faster but I have been stuck for a while. Guess I will look for some tutorials to see how they implement it. Any recomendations? btw thanks a lot guys.

Comment: I'm not sure websockets is even the main issue here. It sounds like maybe the startProcess function is not executing, it's unclear if it's correctly linked to the route or not. Do some simple debugging to verify if the code enters that function, first

Comment: @ADyson Actually, there IS evidence that the function is running.  It's final message is showing up in the log.  I believe the problem is that the framework is not passing a `WebSocketServer` interface to `startProcess`.  You can't just add a parameter and hope that it gets filled in.  Someone has to SEND it.

Comment: In that case, what do you recommend me to do? Because what I do is to start the websocket server in a terminal, but I never link it to anything, only as a parameter.

Comment: Like I said earlier, this needs rearchitecting anyway so the background job runs as a separate process, not as the direct part of a http request

Comment: @TimRoberts sorry you're right I didn't spot that

Answer (score 0):

I'm typing this up as an answer because it is long.

The fundamental disconnect you have here is that your websocket is being opened in a different process from your web server.  If you expect the two to interact, they have to be handled in the same process.  That might mean mixing the two packages, so you can respond to both websocket requests and web server requests.  And note that you'll need some way to associate the two; you cannot assume that you only have one client, so you might have multiple web sockets that you'll need to assign to the proper web session.

Allow me to propose an alternate strategy for what you're talking about.  Instead of creating a web socket, have a Javascript loop in your front-end that polls the back end every second or so using normal `fetch` requests.  That, then, becomes just another API for your back-end to handle, to return the current status of the operation.

This is a very common pattern for handling long-running background tasks, and is way simpler than managing a web socket.  You may even be able to find code for this online.